# Calculate the number of bytes used by a CFStringRef / CFMutableArrayRef

Tags: c, ios, macos, memory-management, core-foundation

I am trying to track memory usage in my program, and I need to know the total memory used for an array of string data.

My strings are represented as CFStringRef, and my array is a CFMutableArrayRef.

On the string I can call CFStringGetLength() to get the number of UTF16 code pairs in the string, but the Apple String Storage guide says that strings can be stored in more compressed formats [1]. Assuming that a UTF16 is 2 bytes, this would give me a conservative upper-bound for sure, which is a good start.

For the mutable array, I could assume that the storage is (length raised to next power of 2) times sizeof(void*).

Is there a better way to calculate the size though? Is there a function to get the bytes allocated for an object derived from CFType?

Failing that, I plan on writing a CFAllocator that proxies all calls to the real CFAllocator that I am using, but records the deltas of the allocations.

[1] http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/Articles/StringStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001179-CJBEJBHH

Comment: my hint: you can use `CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding()` to calculate size for other encodings. Example usage:
`len = CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding(CFStringGetLength(tmp), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using malloc_size() (http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc_size/) to get the size of the allocation for each object.

Comment: That's a good idea. It won't work in all cases unfortunately, since CFType objects don't have to be allocated with malloc. My library accepts a CFAllocatorRef as input, and all input goes through this allocator. Someone could implement a pool-based allocator on top of malloc, and then malloc_size would fail.